# Hand-Translating a C program to Python - grave errors

Tags: python, c, for-loop, primes

Something is amiss. This program calculates the number of primes until a number given by a user and times how long it took to perform the task.

With a 'load value' of 1 (primes till 10^7) , and repeat count of 5 ,

The C code gives the correct " 664579 Primes Processed. Average time taken  = 8.5636 seconds "

The Python code gives " 5000000  Primes processed. Average time taken =  1.9242 "

Which cannot be true since Python is slower and has not found the correct number of primes.

Or perhaps the interpreter runs my program in 4 threads rather than the C code running in just 1, and hence timing is (nearly) 4 times lesser. But the number of primes is still off by more than a 100,000

The C code -

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
unsigned long long bench(double);
int main() {
        double x, time_taken;
        int y;
        clock_t total = 0;
        long long count;
        char loop;
    printf("\nPCB v0.1\nSingle-Threaded Open-source Tool for Benchmarking System Speed.\n\nRecommended Load Value 1 - 3\n");
    while(1) {       
        printf("\nEnter Load Value: ");
        if (scanf("%lf", &x) != 1)
            return 1;
        printf("\nEnter Repeat Count: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &y) != 1)
            return 1;
        x = x * 10000000;
        printf("\nPress Enter to Run ");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        printf("\n(...Running...)\n");

        for (int z = 1; z <= y; z++) {
            clock_t t;
            t = clock();
            count = bench(x);
            t = clock() - t;
            total += t;
            time_taken = ((double)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
        }
        time_taken = ((double)total) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
        printf("\n%lld Primes Processed.\n\nAverage time taken  = %.4f seconds\n",count, time_taken / y);
        printf("\nRe-Run ? (Y/N) : ");
        scanf("%c", &loop);
        if(loop == 'n' || loop == 'N'){
            printf("\nPress Enter to Exit");
            getchar();
            getchar();
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
unsigned long long bench(double x) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= ULLONG_MAX) {
        printf("invalid benchmark range\n");
        return 0;
    }
    register unsigned long long n = ( unsigned long )x;
    register long long count = 0;
    if (n >= 2)
        count++;
    for (register unsigned long long p = 3; p <= n; p += 2) {
        count++;
        for (register unsigned long long i = 3; i * i <= p; i += 2) {
            if (p % i == 0) {
                count--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The Python Code -

```
def bench(x):
    q = 0
    x = int(x)
    count = 0
    if(x>=2):
        count+=1
    for i in range(3,x+1,2):
        count+=1
        for q in range(3,q*q <= i,2):
            if i%q == 0:
                count-=1
                break
    return count

print("PCB v0.1\nSingle-Threaded Open-source Tool for Benchmarking System Speed.\nRecommended Load Value 1 - 3")
import time
while True:
    x = float(input("Enter Load Value: "))
    x = x * 10000000
    y = int(input("Enter Repeat Count: "))
    input("Press Enter to Run")
    print("(...Running...)")
    total = 0

    for z in range(0,y):
        start = time.process_time()
        count = bench(x)
        t = time.process_time() - start
        total += t
        

    print(count," Primes processed.\n\nAverage time taken = ","{:.4f}".format(total/y))
    loop = input(" Re-Run ? (Y/N) : ")
    if loop == 'n' or loop == 'N':
        input("Press Enter to Exit")
        break
```

Comment: First I suggest you split up the C program into smaller pieces, and put them into functions. Then it's easier to translate the functions to another language. And even when split into smaller functions, translate only smaller pieces of the functions one at a time. Smaller pieces of code will also be easier to compare between languages to see if they might do different things.

Comment: And as usual when it comes to unexpected results, *debugging* is the key technique to find and solve such problems. Using a smaller and much more limited data-set as input makes it easier.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I did this over 2 hrs (way longer than it should have taken me) becauyse the C way of thinking and the Python way of thinking are so radically different

Comment: Aside: don't over-complicate the C code with the `register` keyword. The compiler is pretty good at optimising.

Comment: @WeatherVane I also compile for Macs and use Apple Clang for that (in-built) and that thing is bloody stupid, all compilers except for it would do away with a long and intensive for loop whose divisions were never actually used ( bait of code I made to see how well compilers can optimise, and an Android App, did better than Apple Clang) .. So maybe Apple Clang can make loop variables register ones and is good that way, but I don't trust it.

Comment: That is best applied *after* the code is working, if it is plain that the compiler optimisation isn't good enough.  There is a fault here anyway: `unsigned long long n = ( unsigned long )x;`

Comment: @WeatherVane My issue is solved now, but does anyone know if the Interpreted for Python runs the code in all threads by default or no ? Its now taking bloody forever, since its doing it the right way now : took 149.89 seconds ! - so is it running in multiple threads or only one ?

Comment: Is it doing it the right way? When you are building a list of prime numbers, you only need to consider the primes already found as divisors (up to the square root), having seeded the list with `2`. For example, if a number isn't divisible by `3` then it isn't going to be divisible by `9`.

Comment: @WeatherVane efficiency isn't a concern at all, its meant to do some work and report the time taken, sort of as a Bench mark

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood "Its now taking bloody forever", "bench mark" and the usage of `register` keyword.

Comment: @WeatherVane are being sarcastic or do I not understand you ? The expected result is that it will take bloody forever, since its slow sloth Python. And of course register is being used because I want to minimise involvement of memory speeds here, its a test of Integer division a processor. Of course, this is not possible in high level Python, but that's part of what makes them slow !

Comment: We are at cross-purposes: you wrote *Its now taking bloody forever, since its doing it the right way now* and so I commented ways to improve the algorithm.

Comment: Oh ! Now I see... Oh, thanks a lot, but no thanks, since its also (in this case) a rough benchmark of time difference between the two languages ! I could just use the Sieve of Eratosthenes  if I needed a faster algorithm, but that would test memory calls rather than integer math , so despite it being faster, I won't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for q in range(3,q*q <= i,2):
```

This loop (with a dynamic exit test) cannot be expressed as a range.  You need to use a while loop:

```
q = 3
while q*q <= i:
    ...
    q += 2
```

In order to use a Python range for this loop, you would need to determine the final value of `q` in advance, i.e. you'd need the square root of `i`.

Comment: perfect, fixed it !  Python is now being bloody slow as expected. Its been about a minute but no response - ah, finally the proof I was looking for !

Comment: It could be expressed as a range jfyi. Just floor the square root of `i`.

Comment: @PeacefulJames Yes, I added a comment to that effect.  What I meant was that a direct translation wasn't possible using a range.

Comment: @PeacefulJames and Tom, does Python run my code in all threads by default ? It took 149.89 seconds after this, and did it right (correct number of primes for load val 1) because if it does, then C code on one thread is beating it , and if not, results are very expected

Comment: @user13863346 Your code will run in a single thread.  Multiple threads only help if different parts of your code can be run in parallel.  In order to do that, you would need to explicitly set it up to run in multiple threads.

Comment: For those interested , This project is here @ https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19HzjBpu9dbJ0lGWir5Ht5WzFnT33_bV_?usp=sharing

Comment: @TomKarzes: There is currently no way for multiple *threads* to improve CPU-bound performance in the current python due to the dreaded [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). But if you replace the word *thread* with *process* then that can work.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks. I'm not very familiar with Python's thread model and hadn't realized that.